# How can I resize my image proportionally

Tags: javascript, css, image, image-resizing

How can I resize my image like they did here [**website**](http://www.porsche.com/international/#from=/international/en/).

When you zoom in that picture where it says "Radiant Power" , it does not go bigger. Just stays the same size compared to the other elements on the site.

Can you guys give me some tips on how to do that, I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Here's my website: [**site**](http://testwebsite1.herobo.com/)

It's on a free domain so it will load slow.
As you can see I made the big picture work ,because it's 100vw so it's much easier to handle... it stays the same when you zoom in. Now i want the little one to be resized when I zoom in and keep its aspect ratio like that website I showed.

Here's the [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/41tqLk2o/)

That's how I did the large picture resize:

```
    $(function () {
    var scr=screen.width;
    if($(window).width() > scr){
        $("#wall").width(scr + 'px');
        $("#content").width(scr + 'px');
        $("#body-wrap").width(scr + 'px');
        $("header").width(scr + 'px');
        $("ul:eq(0)").width(scr + 'px');
    }
    else{
        $("#wall").width('100vw');
        $("#wall").height('auto');
        $("#body-wrap").width('100vw');
        $("header").width('100vw');
        $("ul:eq(0)").width('100vw');

    }
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if($(window).width() > scr){
            $("#wall").width(scr + 'px');
            $("#content").width(scr + 'px');
            $("#body-wrap").width(scr + 'px');
            $("header").width(scr + 'px');
            $("ul:eq(0)").width(scr + 'px');
        }
        else {
            $("#wall").width('100vw');
            $("#wall").height('auto');
            $("#body-wrap").width('100vw');
            $("header").width('100vw');
            $("ul:eq(0)").width('100vw');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Other images too are staying same on that website.Please add codes what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You just make image scale on percent of total width/height like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/bhdpmhgc/1/

```css
#test{
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.cdn.autocar.co.uk/sites/autocar.co.uk/files/porsche-911-s-gen2-rt-2016-244.jpg" id="test">
```